# Netbeans and grunt issue with console windows 7

Tags: netbeans, gruntjs

I want to run a grunt.js file inside a folder that is inside a netbeans project.

Test 1: 
when I check if grunt is working correct in `c:\Users\someuser`: `grunt -v`
it gets me the grunt version info.

Test 2: 
when Im inside the project folder with grunt inside  
`c:\wamp\www\project\grunt\` (with grunt.js inside)
I run `grunt` or `grunt -v` (just for testing and I get this)

```
The launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse
 it for its own console output.
Closing the console will result in termination of the running program.
Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.
Use '--console new' to create a separate console window.**
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Try using `--console new` and check whether it suppresses this warning and executes your program!

Comment: --console new not recognized as an internal or external command. I also tried grunt --console new which brings me the other messaeg "The launches has deter..."

Comment: Obviously,it referred to `grunt --console new`, not `--console new` on it's own!Anyways,wait for a positive answer.I can't help anymore from distance...

Comment: Now i know that netbeans its opening my grunt file from the console, instead of executing my grunt file. So anyone know if there is a run grunt.js command or disable opening netbeands files from cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed. My mistake. Mi grunt file was Grunt.js not Gruntfile.js

Comment: Satisfied! Cheers MAN.

Comment: @JoseFaro-Now,accept your answer too as it's a bad habit to leave answers unaccepted!